# alive_progress bar not working on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, console, progress-bar

I am trying to use the [alive_progress](https://github.com/rsalmei/alive-progress) alive_bar on PyCharm but it only appears in the console once the whole process has finished. Instead, I want it to display and progress as the for loop operates.

Toy example:

```
from alive_progress import alive_bar
import time

bar_l = 100
with alive_bar(bar_l) as bar:
    for i in range(bar_l):
        time.sleep(0.001)
        bar()
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a option to force enable it and see alive-progress in PyCharm. It's "force_tty=True"

```
with alive_bar(1000, force_tty=True) as bar:
for i in range(1000):
    time.sleep(.01)
    bar()
```